Azure Application Gateway path based wildcard rule issue
We have the path-based rule in Azure Application Gateway to forward requests for dev number-specific requests to the specific backend pool. It’s working perfectly with the following scenarios:
/devXYZ/*
/admin/devXYZ/*
But when a request is for some admin modules, the requests are forwarded to the default backend pool. For example:
/admin/preferences/devXYZ/emailRules
/admin/settings/devXYZ/emailSettings/index
XYZ is dynamic number here. I need to do it for specific numbers.
How can we forward these kind of requests to the specific backend pool?

When you have multiple backend pools and a requirement to route specific backend as mentioned below

/admin/preferences/devXYZ/emailRules
/admin/settings/devXYZ/emailSettings/index

In these scenarios you use "/admin/" if this uses the same backend pool as "/admin/devXYZ/" where this considers as generic rule "/admin/*".
You can still use "/admin/*" - even if this uses a different backendpool than "/admin/devXYZ/*"

You can achieve this by changing the order of the rules but make sure  "/admin/devXYZ/*"  is above the path  "/admin/*"

In general, each path must start with / and may use * as a wildcard character.
For more info on this requirement check with the reference MSDoc mentioned. This wildcard can be used only at the end of the path.

Kindly check with this Microsoft Q&A doc for the follow-up Answer provided by KapilAnanth-MSFT
